# PowerShell -Filters Failing on -notlike comparison

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have this script trying to pull inactive users from AD, but if someone doesn't have a Title, they don't get picked up. I tested the logic on an empty title for a single user, which returned as true, but when it runs through the foreach, it doesn't work (output shows only people with a Title are valid). I thought maybe the lastlogontimestamp comparison wasn't working so I added lastlogondate, but seems the Title is still the problem and I have no idea why?

```
#Inactivity Process

Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

# Gets time stamps for all User in the domain that have NOT logged in since after specified date. Exludes Prism and PlanLink providers.  
$DaysInactive = 365 
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))
$Out_file = "C:\scripts\adcleanup\Inactivity-365days-or-longer_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"
$Out_file2 = "C:\scripts\adcleanup\FailInactivity-365days-or-longer_$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')).csv"

# Get all AD User with lastLogonTimestamp less than our time and set to enabled. Check All Users for this...
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {samaccountname -like "s0*" -and (enabled -eq $true) -and (Title -notlike "*PRISM*") -and (Title -notlike "*PlanLink*") } -Properties samaccountname,name,enabled,Title,LastLogontimestamp, lastlogondate |
select SamAccountname,Name,Title,@{Name="LastLogonTimeStamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}},lastlogondate, enabled 


Foreach ($User in $Users) {

    If (($user.LastLogontimestamp -le $time) -or ($user.LastLogondate -le $time))  {

        $User| export-csv $Out_file -notypeinformation -append

        }

    Else {

        $User | export-csv $Out_file2 -notypeinformation -append 

        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
If (($user.LastLogontimestamp -le $time) -or ($user.LastLogondate -le $time) -or ($user.title -eq "") -and ($user.title -notlike "*PRISM*") -and ($User.title -notlike "*Planlink*") -and (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($user.lastlogondate)))) {
```